# css/jQuery - Alternatives to hidden classes in a table

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working with a responsive-table plugin that uses jQuery and css. It uses the below code which inserts a text header label in every cell of my table, which remains hidden via CSS until the screen size is small enough. The functionality works fine, but it breaks sorting at all screen levels due to the hidden text still being registered by the sort, and it sorts numeric values alphabetically due to the hidden text.

```
 else {
$cells.prepend( "<b class='" + classes.cellLabels + "'>" + text + "</b>"  );
}
```

For example, this will turn a cell value of 10 to be "Header10",  and my numbers will sort like '1, 15, 2' instead of '1,2,15'

So on to my question - I don't know much about javascript/jQuery - is there an alternative to the above line of code that will only insert those headers when the screen size falls into the small range as defined by the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else {
  if($(window).width() > x) {
    $cells.prepend( "<b class='" + classes.cellLabels + "'>" + text + "</b>"  );
  }
}
```

Of course I wouldn't advise using such an approach instead try to give those hidden elements a certain class, and then when you sort your table try to ignore the sort for that class name.

Comment: This works, but is there any way to make this check every time the window is resized? Currently it only checks when the page is loaded.

Comment: you can add a resize handler on the $(window) jQuery object

$(window).on('resize', function() { //your code; });